# Organization of a multi-user application

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

I have a WPF C# multi-user applicaton which interacts with Sql Server Express database. Currently I  have faced up with the following issue:
 How to organize the application and the database in order for several users on different stations be able to work on it , maybe i should put the database file on a server, and make my application on all other stations refer to that server when they interact with the datatbase? If so, how can I provide security of the database file. 
Is there any scenario in which I could install my application on server and sign it as server and while installing on other machines point that server? 
Any advice on general strategies in such cases would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you most certainly can put the database on a server, and in fact, if there are multiple users that's really your only option. First you'll need to build a SQL Server, then  create the database on that server like it is today in development, and then change the connection string in your application to point to that server. In short, there are a **lot** of areas you're going to need to learn about and this question is a bit too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-user application, you definitely should put the database onto a server. And because the application is for multi-users, the first screen shown when a user opens the application is the login screen (just like the case of web application).

Security isn't a matter, once a database is put in the filesystem, only the users on that computer can access it. And of course, the computer which contains databases is supposed to have only administrators as users. Another point is that Windows may have IIS running, don't put the database files under public root of IIS so that non-user people won't be able to download them through HTTP.

Let's say the users are working on the same office. You can assign any computer in the LAN as a server and install the database on it. Any computer in the same LAN has a LAN IP (eg. 192.168.1.100), your application can connect to this IP for database operations.

Comment: Your advice is in the right are, but there are some over-simplifications that worry me.  First (and least important), it's worth noting that you don't need a login screen if you can use Windows authentication.  More importantly, your second point isn't correct: users *can* access files from other computers, based on access rules and file/sharing security, so security is still a *massively* important matter!  You also oversimplify use of LAN connections: many offices would use DHCP for non-server machines, so running the server on "any computer" might only work until a DHCP lease expires.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Is it true that in this scenario I have to deploy my application in two ways: one for installation on a server machine, in which both installation of sql server express and the database will be embedded, and the other one for client machines, that will contain only data referring to the application?

Comment: @khurshed_nosirov, yeah 2 parts i believe: Your .net application runs on each client machine. The server holds the SQL Server database.

Comment: @Paul Dinh, Is it right that client machines don't need to have sqlserver express installed on them?

Comment: yes. you don't need SQL Server on the client machines. what you need is "using System.Data.SqlClient;": http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Answer (score 1):

If all the users are concurrent then your going to need to place the SQL instance on a server that they all have access too..

your also going to need to know look at quite a few things like this such as how your going to manage your transactions and just how your persistence layer is going to function in general.

each of those topics are probably going to breed many more SO questions :)

this could help for some inspiration on how your going to structure the persistance layer..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx